# -bash: command substitution: line XX: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash

Why does the following code give me the error in the title?

```
_say_hey()
{
    echo "hey"
}
echo "$(_say_hey())"
```

Answer (score 7):

When calling a function, call it like an ordinary command (leave off the brackets):

```
echo "$(_say_hey)"
```

Note that the `echo` here is redundant; you could just write `_say_hey` on a line by itself for the same effect.